# Cocoa listen for mouse move events when the mouse moves, not the cursor

Tags: cocoa, appkit

I'm developing a game in `Cocoa`, and I want to rotate the camera when the user moves the mouse, and the screen is limiting the camera movement. I hid the mouse cursor, but I want to listen when the physical mouse moves, not when the mouse cursor moves. I've heard about `IOKit` but that seems to be too low level. If it is any high-level way to do that, then how? And else, how do I use `IOKit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you hide the cursor, call `CGAssociateMouseAndMouseCursorPosition(FALSE)`. That will make it so that mouse movement does not move the cursor.

You will continue to get `NSEventTypeMouseMoved`, `NSEventTypeLeftMouseDragged`, `NSEventTypeRightMouseDragged`, and `NSEventTypeOtherMouseDragged` events as the mouse is moved (depending on whether buttons are pressed during the move). Because the cursor isn't moving, the `locationInWindow` won't be meaningful. It will continue to report the last location from when you disassociated the cursor from the mouse. However, the `deltaX` and `deltaY` properties will indicate how far and in what direction the mouse moved.